# absolute image left side in the container

Tags: html, css, css-position

I use foundation grid, but I need to keep this grid and make an absolute left and right column with an image for full width, I've already made the right side with image and left side with text and gray background. But I can not make the same thing that image should be on left side and the gray background to the right side.

```
enter code here
<div class="form-banner form-banner--medium form-banner-placement--right">
    <div class="form-banner-container">
      <div class="form-banner-wrapper form-banner-wrapper--original"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/blue/fff&text=image+here">
        <div class="form-banner-left">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="columns"><span class="tag">recommended</span>
                <div class="spacer-15">&nbsp;</div>
              <h3>Monitoring</h3>
                <div class="spacer-30">&nbsp;</div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias distinctio explicabo suscipit eligendi ratione asperiores unde amet expedita vero numquam magnam officiis veniam natus tempora in vel, ipsam cupiditate dolorem.</p>
                <div class="spacer-40">&nbsp;</div><a class="button secondary small">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  .form-banner {
     position: relative;
     background: white;
     overflow: hidden;
      }
  .form-banner img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
       bottom: 0;
     }
  .form-banner-container {
     max-width: rem-calc(1200);
     height: 100%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding-left: rem-calc(20);
     padding-right: rem-calc(20);
     }
     .form-banner-wrapper {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0 -9600rem;
       padding-left: 9600rem;
       padding-right: 9600rem;
       position: relative;
       z-index: 0;
        }
      .form-banner-wrapper:before {
       content: "";
       z-index: -1;
       width: 50%;
        background-color: gray;
       }

     .form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper {
        padding-bottom: rem-calc(100);
     }
   .form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper img {
     position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 9600rem;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
       z-index: -2;
     height: 100%;
     width: 50vw;
     object-fit: cover;
     object-position: 50% 50%;
   }
  .form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper:before {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
   }
  .form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 50%;
   }
   .form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper--         original:after {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
   }
   .form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    left: 9600rem;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5rem;
   }

   .form-banner--large .form-banner-left {
    padding: rem-calc();
   }

  .form-banner--920px .form-banner-left {
     padding: rem-calc();
     }

   .form-banner--125 {
    height: 85;
    }
   .form-banner--125 .form-banner-left {
     padding: rem-calc(160);
      }

   .form-banner--large {
       height: 920px;
    }

     .form-banner--medium {
      height: 466px;
      }
```

I prived code on codepen [Codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/QKRRam)

[image]

Comment: I'm going to have to ask for a little more clarity on what you're trying to achieve here. You want to swap the image and the grey background?

Comment: I want move the image to left and text with gray background to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out, hope its helps you:

```css
.form-banner {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-banner-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 -9600rem;
  padding-left: 9600rem;
  padding-right: 9600rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.form-banner-container {
  max-width: rem-calc(1200);
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: rem-calc(20);
  padding-right: rem-calc(20);
}

/*=========================================================
  01. #FORM BANNER PLACEMENT RIGHT
=========================================================*/
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: rem-calc(100);
}
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper img {
float: left;
z-index: -2;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
object-fit: cover;
object-position: 50% 50%;
}
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
}
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper--original:after {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-left {
width: 45%;
padding: 6rem 2.5%;
float: right;
background-color: gray;
}

/*=========================================================
  03. #FORM BANNER SIZE
=========================================================*/
.form-banner--large .form-banner-left {
  padding: rem-calc();
}

.form-banner--920px .form-banner-left {
  padding: rem-calc();
}

.form-banner--125 {
  height: 85;
}
.form-banner--125 .form-banner-left {
  padding: rem-calc(160);
}

.form-banner--large {
  height: 920px;
}

.form-banner--medium {
  height: 466px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-banner form-banner--medium form-banner-placement--right">
        <div class="form-banner-container">
          <div class="form-banner-wrapper form-banner-wrapper--original"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/blue/fff&text=image+here">
            <div class="form-banner-left">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="columns"><span class="tag">recommended</span>
                    <div class="spacer-15">&nbsp;</div>
                  <h3>Monitoring</h3>
                    <div class="spacer-30">&nbsp;</div>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias distinctio explicabo suscipit eligendi ratione asperiores unde amet expedita vero numquam magnam officiis veniam natus tempora in vel, ipsam cupiditate dolorem.</p>
                    <div class="spacer-40">&nbsp;</div><a class="button secondary small">Read More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/b3bzm9r3/)

Answer (score 1):

classes edited

```
.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 50%;
left: 9600rem;
bottom: 0;
z-index: -2;
height: 100%;
width: 50vw;
object-fit: cover;
object-position: 50% 50%;
}

.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-left {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 9600rem;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
padding-top: 5rem;
}

.form-banner-placement--right.form-banner .form-banner-wrapper:before {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 9600rem;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
}
```

[JSfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mar1/vtcw60kc/)